# SQL, label user based on the similarity

Tags: sql, database, label, rdbms

Is below case possible in SQL?

Let say I have a table like this:

| user_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 122 |
| 1 | 121 |
| 2 | 124 |
| 2 | 125 |
| 2 | 121 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 3 | 122 |
| 3 | 122 |
| 4 | 123 |
| 4 | 212 |
| 4 | 222 |
| 5 | 124 |
| 5 | 125 |
| 5 | 121 |

I want to label the user if they have same product_id, regardless the order, so the output looks like this:

| user_id | product_id | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a |
| 1 | 122 | a |
| 1 | 121 | a |
| 2 | 124 | b |
| 2 | 125 | b |
| 2 | 121 | b |
| 3 | 123 | a |
| 3 | 121 | a |
| 3 | 122 | a |
| 4 | 123 | c |
| 4 | 212 | c |
| 4 | 222 | c |
| 5 | 124 | b |
| 5 | 125 | b |
| 5 | 121 | b |

Please advise

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you have to tag your DBMS, the answer may be product-specific.

Comment: no dbms tag. i tag it as rdbms as well.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL or something else?

Comment: I will do it on BigQuery and Impala, @ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string_agg` function to get the list of product_ids for each user (as a single string), then use the `dense_rank` function on that string to get unique labels for each product_ids list.

```
select T.user_id, T.product_id, D.label
from table_name T join
(
  select user_id, 
    chr(dense_rank() over (order by user_products) + 96) label
  from
  (  
   select user_id, 
    string_agg(cast(product_id as string), ',' order by product_id)  user_products
   from table_name
   group by user_id
  ) lbl
) D
on T.user_id = D.user_id
order by T.user_id
```